# Prevent microtype's textls from add space before word division hyphen

Tags: microtype

Is there any way to prevent microtype's textls from add space before word division hyphen?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyretermes}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=3:2]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \footnote{Obszerne i filozoficznie istotne wyjaśnienia dotyczące rozstrzygalności zawiera książka A. \textls{Grzegorczyka}, \emph{Zagadnienia rozstrzygalności}, PWN, Warszawa 1957.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you *really* need to letter space?

Comment: That isn't a real space.  It's what you've asked for with letterspace.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I have to use letter space because my task is to make digital copy of some book for my University's Publishing house and in print edition was used letter spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know that's not a real space. I started for fun (LaTeX is one of my hobbies) project of making copy of Philosophy of mathematics book that I used to learn from to one of my PhD exams. Then I proposed my University's Publishing house to publish (author granted a permission) it in digital because this book has only one edition from 2004. After cheking draft version one of tech staff members asked me to get rid of that space but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Sigh.  The person who's asking apparently isn't familiar with printing traditions.  The "phony space" could be eliminated by letterspacing that word manually.  You might take a closer look at the original book to see if there are any hyphenated letterspaced words, to see what they look like.